Compile a code on WSL with Visual Studio 2022
I try to compile a C++ code on WSL with Visual Studio 2022, but the compiler doesn't see my libraries these installed on WSL. However, VS Code can compile it as very well.
How do I make the $PATH of Ubuntu that is installed on Windows by WSL known to Visual Studio 2022?

